# How can I open a Chrome window with exec.Command()?

Tags: go

I would like to wrote a Go program to open a Chrome window with the URL passed to it as parameters.

So I wrote something like this.

```golang
package main

import "os"  
import "os/exec"  
import "strings"  

func main() {  
    args := "--app=" + strings.Join(os.Args\[1:\], "")  
    exec.Command("\\"C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Google\\\\Chrome Dev\\\\Application\\\\chrome.exe\\"", args).Start()  
}
```

But when I run the program `go run ".\abc.go" "https://google.com"`, nothing happens.

I tried `exec.Command("cmd", "\\C", "start", "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome Dev\\Application\\chrome.exe\"", args).Start()` too but no luck.

Comment: Check your errors.

Comment: There was no error message printed to the console. Looks like it runs normally, but no window comes up

Comment: Not the console. When writing Go programs, you must check the error return of functions that you call, and deal with any errors that occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on windows you can do

```
err := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "start", "chrome.exe").Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I finally got it working by removing the `start` argument, like `exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "start", "chrome.exe").Run()`. The `start` keyword start Chrome in console mode instead of starting it with GUI. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Accepted :) Thanks